# C# Regular Expression To Check for a string in pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check on string a regular expression where it says if a target string is within braces in the target string.

Example

```
string keyword = "word";
string wholeText1 = "test test word test test { something else }";
string wholeText2 = "test test something else { word }";
```

So, i want an expression where i can conclude True or False.

I haven't really gotten anywhere and I have 0 knowledge of regular express.
Thanks for anyone who is willing to give me a quick help.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: What is it with these "write this regex for me" questions? We're **not** going to do that for you. Read a tutorial, pick up a book, try something, show that you are at least interested in understanding the solution.

Comment: *Give a man a fish he eats for a day, teach him to fish though and.......*

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind not using regular expressions:

```
var startindex = wholeText1.IndexOf("{");
var endindex = wholeText1.IndexOf("}", startindex);

return wholeText1.Substring(startindex, endindex).Contains(keyword);
```

Comment: This will fail on "{}keyword {}". Whether that matches the 'spec' is debtable - it does check whether keyword is between '{' and '}', but not whether they are open at the time. Ignore this comment, I'm wrong.

Comment: This will not fail because it isn't within brackets. A close bracket means the end of the bracket, otherwise you will never be able to determine "between brackets" in the first place.

Comment: However, it will fail erroneously on `'{} {keyword}'` won't it?

Comment: yes, it will only look for the first occurrence within brackets. If you want more than one bracket, use a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex. Just do `text.Contains("{ " + keyword + " }");`

Answer (score 0):

```
    bool CheckTargetString(String str,String key)
    {
        int firstIndex = str.IndexOf("{");
        int lastIndex = str.IndexOf("}");
        int keyIndex = str.IndexOf(key);
        return (keyIndex > firstIndex && keyIndex < lastIndex);
    }
```

Comment: That will return true if the string contains either an opening or closing brace.

Comment: @David : Could you please check it now.

Comment: That's much better :)

Comment: :) Thanks David , actually I didn't get the problem first time.Thanks.